# Updating multiple columns with C# with stored procedure in MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

I've been bashing my head in on this one, and I'm stumped. I haven't been able to find any error beyond:

'SAFE PMA Members.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\6.0.22\System.Diagnostics.StackTrace.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'SAFE PMA Members.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\6.0.22\System.Reflection.Metadata.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'SAFE PMA Members.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\6.0.22\System.Collections.Immutable.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
Exception thrown: 'System.FormatException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll

I'm trying to update member records using WinForms for a decent portfolio project.

This is my stored procedure on a remote MySQL server where the running computer's IP address is whitelisted. It works in MySQL workbench when that is connected to the server and the values are entered in.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE updates_member(IN p_id INT, IN p_firstName VARCHAR(30), IN p_lastName VARCHAR(30), IN p_phoneNumber VARCHAR(15),
    IN p_email VARCHAR(100), IN p_streetAddress VARCHAR(100), IN p_city VARCHAR(30), IN p_state VARCHAR(20), IN p_zipCode INT(1), IN p_balance int(1), IN p_lastBalUpdate date)
BEGIN
UPDATE members
SET
firstName = p_firstName, lastName = p_lastName, phoneNumber = p_phoneNumber, email = p_email, streetAddress = p_streetAddress, city = p_city, state = p_state, zipCode = p_zipCode, balance = p_balance, lastBalUpdate = p_lastBalUpdate WHERE id = p_id;
END //
DELIMITER ;;
```

The code for the program is here:

```
public string MemberUpdate(Member input)
{
    using var connection = new MySqlConnection
        (Helper.connVal("members"));
    string calling = "updates_member";
    string Msg = "";

    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(calling, connection);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@p_id", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = input.id;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@p_firstName", MySqlDbType.VarString).Value = input.FirstName;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@p_lastName", MySqlDbType.VarString).Value = input.LastName;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@p_phoneNumber", MySqlDbType.VarString).Value = input.PhoneNumber;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@p_email", MySqlDbType.VarString).Value = input.Email;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@p_streetAddress", MySqlDbType.VarString).Value = input.StreetAddress;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@p_city", MySqlDbType.VarString).Value = input.City;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@p_state", MySqlDbType.VarString).Value = input.State;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@p_zipCode", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = input.ZipCode;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@p_balance", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = input.CurrentBalance;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@p_LastBalUpdate", MySqlDbType.Date).Value = input.LastBalUpdate;

    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        connection.Close();
        Msg = "Successfully updated.";
    }
    catch 
    {
        Msg = "Error while updating";
    }

    return Msg;
}
```

The program keeps returning the message "Error while updating" which is fine, but I haven't been able to figure out how to get the stored procedure to work through this WinForms program. I'm pretty new to coding in C# and greatly appreciate any help with getting this to work and possibly finding where the error log is.

Edit: I've been able to retrieve data with a stored procedure so far in this program, but updating columns is what this issue is.

Comment: Attach the error along with the full stacktrace

Comment: I am not a WinForms or C# dev, but generically "swallowing" exceptions in this way seems like a bad idea. You would be better off just letting the exceptions bubble, at least during early stage of dev. I don't know if [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-stored-proc.html) is relevant, but in the examples they use `AddWithValue` and specify the param's direction.

Comment: "AddWithValue" and specifying the direction was the problem, it works now! Post that as the answer and thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The examples given in the [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-stored-proc.html) use `AddWithValue` and specify the parameter's direction.

Using your first parameter as an example, instead of:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@p_id", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = input.id;
```

you would use:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p_id", input.id);
cmd.Parameters["@p_id"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
```